# git repository in "mega"-share folder has the error "fatal: bad object HEAD". How to prevent that?

Tags: git

I have a git repository which is syncronized via "mega"-share. I use it on different machines and somtimes on some machines I get the error:

```
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

I guess it has to do with synchronization errors. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use a shared-folder to store `.git` directories.  Git has its own sharing protocols (via `git push` and `git fetch`), and it does not play well with other sharing protocols.  In particular, there are higher level requirements for making changes across multiple separate files in particular orders and with particular behaviors, that low-level file-at-a-time sharing will violate.

(It's possible, sometimes, to use the kind of sharing that virtual machine systems like VMWare or Vagrant implement, to share a `.git` folder between host and VM-image, or between different VM images.  But there are some tricky constraints on this, and it's best not to do it at all.)

Comment: That's too bad. So I need to commit & push all my stuff if I change my computer? Is there a better way, if my changes are ready for committing?

Comment: Commit and push-or-fetch is how I do it, across different machines running different OSes. Even in my VMs, I now use push/fetch, it just works a lot better.